# Java Multiple key presses and release

Tags: java, keylistener

I've tried searching how to handle multiple key presses in java but all the solutions I've found are assuming that all keys are pressed.

I'm creating a very simple game where an image that I loaded will be moving along a canvas. i want it to move left, right, and jump by using the left, right, and up arrow keys. My problem is that, when I press the left and right keys, they work perfectly fine. But, when I press the up arrow key, it just jumps and stops moving all together.

I have an array list of all keys pressed and a run() method that checks all the keys pressed and does the specific job. But java only remembers the latest key that I pressed and it doesn't call the run() method once I press the up arrow key.

What do you suggest I do? I've tried threads but they mix up my code (or maybe I did something wrong?).

Here's my code:

```
public class Moving implements KeyListener {
    ProgramClass bg; //this is another class
    Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public Moving (ProgramClass aa) {
        bg = aa;
    }

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent ae) {
        pressed.add(ae.getKeyCode());
        run();
    }

    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent ae) {
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent ae) {
        pressed.remove (ae.getKeyCode());
        if (bg.left==false) {
            if (ae.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                bg.yy -=40;
            }
        }
        run();
    }

    public void run () {
        if (bg.left==true) {
            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {}

            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
                if (bg.pic==true)
                    bg.pic = false;
                else
                    bg.pic = true;

                if (bg.x==-550)
                    bg.x = -2;
                else
                    bg.x -= 2;
            }
        }

        if (bg.left==false) {
            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                if (bg.pic==true)
                    bg.pic = false;
                else
                    bg.pic = true;

                if (bg.x==550)
                    bg.x = 2;
                else
                    bg.x += 2;
            }

            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {}

            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
                bg.yy -=40;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not pretty clear in which context your `Moving` class is running. If understood correctly, your run method should be called in some kind of loop instead of being called each time a key is pressed.

Comment: I never considered putting it inside a loop and I THANK YOU so much for that suggestion! :) It took me quite some time to figure out where to put the loop. I managed it by creating a method for updating the values and creating a thread that loops through the method. :D

Comment: heh, np, glad to help! Hope it's working as intended now :]